# How to re-install Windows 8 for ASUS Ultrabook

Tags: windows-8, boot, partitioning, recovery-partition

I bought a S550CM Ultrabook from ASUS a few weeks ago. I tried to resize the partitions but it seems that I screwed up something. Now I can't boot anymore nor use the recovery process / "reset to factory settings" options. My best bet at this point would be to reinstall from a fresh CD/USB/DVD.

Since these laptops don't come with a Win8 install CD, I'm kinda stuck here. I don't have the CD Key either for my Win8 activation, although I hear that it is written somewhere in the BIOS, so this seems to be less of a problem.

The recovery partition don't seem to work either. I tried dumping them with WinPE, I now have the two main recovery partition from my large disk (750 BG). There is also a smaller SSD disk that I haven't touched yet (24 GB). I dumped the recovery partitions into `.wim` files, but it doesn't seem to be bootable images.

Is there somewhere I can download Windows 8 for this laptop, write it to a removable device, then reinstall with that? Any suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have been through same condition many times and my first time was the second day since I purchased my laptop 5 years ago.

From my experience I would simply ask you to follow these steps, you don't even have to install your OS again. Following steps will do the job.

```
 1. Download the Windows 8 iso (Download the version based on your
    current system support i.e. x86/x64).

 2. Create a Bootable USB drive from this iso using [Windows 7 USB DVD Download Tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) Or [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).

 3. Now boot from your USB Device.

 4. Select your Keyboard and region language when prompted.

 5. Click Repair and let the process to be completed.

 6. When it completes, reboot your laptop. If everything is fixed, your OS will boot. (Forget the further steps, you are done).

 7. If it doesn't, Boot from USB again and repeat the above steps till step 4

 8. Click Install

 9. Agree the Terms

 10. Select Custom and Click Next

 11. Select your Drive on which you want to Install OS (You can also format the drive here).
```

Now let all the steps to complete, your PC will boot several times during the installation process.

Follow the steps after, Create Username and set other things. and you are done.

I hope this'll help you.

Comment: Do you know where I can find a win 8 iso?

Comment: You can follow these steps for download: [Here](http://www.redmondpie.com/download-windows-8-iso-x86-x64-file-directly-from-microsoft/). In other case you can also find Windows 8 Iso on Torrents, but I don't think if it's legal.

By the way @user1190 why don't you upgrade to Windows 8.1? Its even better than Windows 8

Comment: this will need Windows 8 product Key which he doesn't have. Also Microsoft has disabled upgrade assistant for Windows 8

Comment: Did your laptop came with Windows 8 installed? If yes you can find its key on laptop base or behind your battery case

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Windows 8 Recovery Drive. Well, as you can't access your computer, try asking any of your friend if he has Windows 8 installed. If yes, then ask him to do the following below steps:

**PREREQUISITES:** An at least 1 GB USB with 500 MB free space.

1. Open Control Panel and navigate to System and Security > Action Center > Recovery (at bottom of windows)
2. In the windows that opens, click on *Create a Recovery Drive*.
3. You will now see a Recovery Window. Now insert a USB (make sure any other external drives are not inserted).
4. DO NOT CHECK COPY PARTITION (RECOVERY) TO USB. JUST CLICK NEXT.
5. Now your USB will be recognized. Select it and proceed to Next.
6. Now create the recovery partition. EVERYTHING ON USB WILL BE ERASED OR FORMATTED.
7. When finished, you will be greeted by the message!

Now comes your part....

1. Insert the USB to your system before turning on the PC.
2. Turn your PC and immediately press the Boot Menu button (refer to manufacturer).
3. Select USB boot option.
4. Now, as recovery drive finishes booting a blue-friendly screen will appear.
5. Just click on Fix Start-up option.
6. Windows will identify the issue and will fix it for you.

***EVERYTHING DONE! HAVE A NICE DAY!***

Answer (score -1):

A lot a computers now a days don't have a license key attached to them cause they are incorporated through the drivers and programs in order to get the proper drivers and such you need the factory install disk USB flash drive in order to have it run at its best performance for asus the have a download Center for the drivers like most computers and can order the factory reset disk from asus for 45 plus tax in b.c Canada chat with a customer rep. They will send you a link or try finding a clean disk with all the windows 8 systems like starter and home pro ultimate don't forget the x64 or such and like wise for other operating systems

Comment: This is inaccurate and unreadable.  Not a usable answer.